# Accessing global class

Tags: ios, swift, global

I have a class `Style`, which I access it in one of my view controllers:

```
class Style {
    static var textSize: CGFloat = 17

    deinit {
        print("i have been deinitiated")
    }
}
```

When I open this view controller, it sets the textSize to `30`:

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Style.textSize = 30

        let label = UILabel()

        label.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        label.text = "Some text"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: Style.textSize, weight: .light)

        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

When I go back to my initial view controller and `SecondVC` is deallocated, the textSize of `Style` is still `30`.

What happens to the class `Style`? When running instruments I don't see anything about the class `Style`. I understand the class `Style` is never initialized, but where does it save the information of `textSize`?

Comment: Why do you think that the value of `textSize` should go back to 17 from 30?

Comment: remember when you say `var` you are telling that variable that it has the ability to be mutated so after you assigned 30 to the variable it would no longer be 17 but 30

Comment: If `textSize` doesn't go back to `17`, it only feels natural to me that it is saved somewhere. Does that mean it will always be `30` until the app is closed and open again? I'm sorry I don't really understand it yet, is there any documentation I could read about this? Googling this gives me no results.

Comment: Read about [Type Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) in the Swift book.

Comment: static var means can access the property from class instead of initial a instance, also static property store in `data` area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a `Global` class then use a `Singleton` instead with an `instance`:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    var textSize = CGFloat()
}
```

Assign the value:

```
Singleton.sharedInstance.textSize = 30
```

Get the value:

```
let textSize = Singleton.sharedInstance.textSize.count
```

By doing this you make sure that there are only one instance that you can call for your `Singleton` and you´ll get the values for that instance.

This is according to Apples preferred Singleton style. Read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a `static var` in class `Style` with value `17`, now it is stored in the `data`. when `Style.textSize = 30` has been executed, the `textSize` becomes `30`, and when the `SecondVC` has been `deinit-ed`, it didn't affect the `textSize` because they have no relation. The `textSize` is still `30`.

When u say `Style.textSize = 30` the `Style` is not `Style()` not a property of the `SecondVC`, but just a class reference use for call the static var `textSize`

If you change `static var textSize: CGFloat = 17` to `var textSize: CGFloat = 17` and `Style.textSize = 30` to `Style().textSize = 30` you will see the difference.

Also you may want read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)

Answer (score 1):

static variable is never getting released as long as the application is running. The static lives forever.  Below code will call deinit once set style = nil

```
class Style {
  var textSize: CGFloat = 17

  deinit {
    print("i have been deinitiated")
  }
}

class Singleton  {

  static weak var weakReference : Style?
  static var shared: Style {
    get {
      guard let style  = weakReference  else {
          let style = Style()
          weakReference = style
          return style
      }
      return style
      }
    }
}

class SecondVC: UIViewController {

   var str: Style? = Singleton.shared
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        str?.textSize = 30
        str = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

search swift static ,or read the The Swift Programming Language (Properties),you will get the answer. the important is "static"

Comment: why? I have give the right methods ,because my english is to poor,  and i have get the answer with this